# how to submit the form without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to add product in to the cart using jQuery and AJAX. The situation is that I am getting more then 30 forms that are generated dynamically using foreach loop. after page loading i get product list but need to add only one product in to the cart , and dont want reload the page , so i am using AJAX.  please help me how can i achieve this.

Most important thing is when i tried without `<form>` tag , the value of productId always goes 1 because its the first value of id attribute, and saves product in to the cart whose id is one.  So I am using `<form>`.

**this is code (its a sample code) :**

```
<form id="addToCartForm" action="" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" id="productId" value="${products.productid}">
    <button id="btnSubmit">Add to Cart</button>
</form>

<form id="addToCartForm" action="" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" id="productId" value="${products.productid}">
    <button id="btnSubmit">Add to Cart</button>

</form>

<form id="addToCartForm" action="" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" id="productId" value="${products.productid}">
    <button id="btnSubmit">Add to Cart</button>

</form>
```

I already tried lots of things, like `jquery.form.min.js`, but nothing is going on as according just i like want.

please help. thnx in advance.

**Edited**

**script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".addToCart").click(function(){

     $.post('addToCart.htm', {productId: $('input[type=hidden]#productIdId').val()},
         function(message){
         $("#message").html(message); 
         }
     );
    });
 });
```

Comment: Use ajax of jQuery. id should be unique.

Comment: where is your javascript codes?

Comment: Separate form for each product on the page sounds like deadly wrong solution.

Comment: Why your all form ids are same??

Comment: Please show the relevant JavaScript code. It's impossible to say what's wrong with your code without seeing it. Otherwise just google for "jquery submit form with ajax", there are literally hundreds of guides available.

Comment: What did you try so far? Note that an id should be an unique identifier, so you should to use classes.

Comment: the problem isn't with the form tag, it's the fact that every iteration of the form elements has the same ID

Comment: All ids are same because the are all generated by foreach loop

Comment: so are all the value="..."s and you managed to make them unique....

Comment: @Sohail Then add the iterator to the ID. So it becomes `addToCartForm1`, `addToCartForm2` and so on.

Comment: @saty.. Not only form ids, also the `ids` of controls inside the form are same.. ;)

Comment: @JLow se then how to write one code in jquery for all of them ??? please elaborate.

Comment: There is no element with the class `addToCart` in your provided html-markup.

Comment: @empiric `addToCart` i added in the form submit button , in question i forget to add this .

Comment: @Sohail try the answers solutions, both are valid. Remember that `$(this)` represents the element which has triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$("#addToCartForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        action: $form.attr("action"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

UPDATE: Oh! and yeah, the IDs of your forms should be unique.

UPDATE 2: Without forms

```
<a class="addToCart" href="#" data-productid="${products.productid}">Add to Cart</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".addToCart").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajaxPost({
        action: "addToCart.html",
        data: {productId: $(this).data("productid")}
    }).done(function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Problem is that all ids are generated by a loop so they are all same.

Comment: Use a class instead of an id then

Comment: @Sohail then you should change that loop.

Comment: My input field is hidden and its value is through loop. without `form` tag  value of productid always goes one to the controller . and product add to cart whose id is one always , its not matter which product i am adding to the cart.

Comment: @Sohail you could use an <a> tag, or even a <button> tag, without any form; but you would need to put the value of productId in that tag, not in a hidden <input> tag.

Comment: @MauricePerry so i need to create hyperlink with productid and than i should put jQuery aJax on that hyperlink . am i right ??

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function(){
    var value = $(this).prev().val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/server/script',
        type: 'post',
        data: { productid: value },
        success: function(){
            alert('succeeded');
        }
    });
});
```

Anyway, you have to use classes instead ids if you have same kind elements. An id is an identifier, so it must to be unique.